# How to iterate over a javascript object creating HTML to be placed into an E-mail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like help with iterating over a javascript object where each key:value pair is written on a new line in an email body using Appscript so I think it needs to be converted to a HTML string, but I am unsure. The code I have is below.

```
let dictionary = {}
  const gratitude = dataRange.filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] >= result && row[10] != 'Gratitude' && row[10] != 'Notes' && row[10] != ''
  }).map(function(row) {
    return dictionary[row[0]] = row[10]
  })

var message = {
    to: 'person1@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Weekly Summary',
    body: 
    `
    This week you completed:
    
    ${dictionary}`,
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify whether it is necessary for `dictionary` to remain an objecty object rather than an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be easier to use an array that can readily be converted to a text string with `.join()`. Try this:

```
  const body = dataRange
    .filter(row => row[0] >= result && row[10] !== 'Gratitude' && row[10] !== 'Notes' && row[10] !== '')
    .map(row => [row[0], row[10]].join(': '))
    .join('\n');
  const message = {
    to: 'person1@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Weekly Summary',
    body: 'This week you completed:\n\n' + body,
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```